# Making an image with a transparent background

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pstricks, backgrounds

I do not know what is the official term for such images, but if I make an image in TikZ or `pstricks` then I want it to have no background; for example I might post it on a webpage with a different background than white, then it should blend in nicely.

I have seen a couple of images in wikipedia that are like this ([example](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aKnot_table.svg)), and they show up on image viewers to have some kind of a checkered background.

Comment: the buzz word is "transparent background" and TikZ is giving you that automatically if I am not wrong.

Comment: wait you want to convert it to an image file? Like .png or .gif?

Comment: @percusse yes (..char limit...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you want to convert to an image file, the problem is one of the converter pdf -> image. TikZ as such does not fill the background (unless you do so explicitly).

If you use ImageMagick, you can use `convert -transparent white` during the conversion. Other programs may require a transparency channel (perhaps you need to create one based on the color "white" as well).

Answer (score 4):

Converting any image (rasterized or vector-based) to a "transparent background image" would have to be performed by an external program. TeX's output is either postscript or PDF. If you want to port LaTeX/graphic code to SVG format specifically, consider reading up on [SVG LaTeX](http://svgkit.sourceforge.net/SVGLaTeX.html).